# Microsoft reporting services vs ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

is there any difference between ms reporting services & ssrs? Does ssrs succeed ms reporting services?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they are both the same thing.

Microsoft reporting services was the original name for an addon service made available in 2004 for SQL server 2000.

Microsoft SQL server reporting services (SSRS) is what it became know as in subsequent releases for SQL server 2005 and SQL server 2008.

The two terms are interchangeable.